# Send data to API via Ajax

Tags: ajax, api

I have simple form for sending email dato to API, but i want send data via Ajax for not reaload page and give success message under input tag.

[HTML Sending form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFYfd.png)

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="send-modal-data">
    <input type="text" id="send_email" name="subscribe-email" class="modal-input" placeholder="Email *">
    <button name="subscribe-form" class="danger-btn send-subscribe">Send</button>           
</form>
```

**Ajax**

```
  $(function() {
    $(".send-subscribe").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var settings = {
       email:  $("#send_email"),
      "url": "xxxx/api/user/trial/subscribe?email=" + email,
      "method": "POST",
      "timeout": 0,
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });

    });
});
```

But when i send email, my modal window closing and not send data, how i can realize with right way ?

Comment: Please elaborate on the steps you've taken. What is the current behavior or what is the error you're receiving? This can help others narrow down the problem. Apart from this, it will also help them to elaborate on it

Comment: A `button` **without** `type` makes a `type="submit"` by default. And that's why the form is submitted by html and not by js. Do a `e.preventDefault` to prevent the submit form

Comment: @MikeSli i edit my post, please see

Comment: @Roy I add type="submit" and e.preventDefault but not action, still same problem

Comment: @YavarMammadov Update your question and I will check if it works.

Comment: @Roy i already updated my quession

Comment: @YavarMammadov I don't see the preventDefault.

Comment: @Roy please refresh, i added

Comment: @YavarMammadov you forgot to declare `e` on `$(".send-subscribe").click(function(e) {` and is not `e.preventDefaul` is `e.preventDefault`

Comment: @Roy I added, but still reloads the page and does not send the date

Comment: @YavarMammadov Did you read about the correction in `preventDefaul` to `preventDefault` (with a final T) ?

Comment: @Roy oh, sorry my mistake, i add T but when click to button give this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: email is not defined"

Comment: @YavarMammadov That's because `email is not defined`. declare it `var email = $("#send_email").val()` (check the important of `val()`) and use it.

Comment: @Roy i want add email data to end of api address, after equal, this way with var email not working

Comment: @YavarMammadov `$("#send_email")` is not data, is a `jQuery object` so, try using `.val()` to get the text inside `#send_email`. And make the `var email ..` before declare the `var settings`...

Comment: @Roy thanks a lot for great job !) last quession, how get success msj and display it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your post function should look something like this:

```
$(".send-subscribe").click(function() {
    $.post("https://xxx/api/user/subscribe", {
        email : $("#send_email")
    }, function(data, status){
        console.log(status + " :: " + data);
    });
});
```

You than can use status and data to continue your work.